# How can I make a simple flow chart in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I come to you with a question on how I can create a simple flow chart like in the pictures below in SSRS. I have a query that returns rows with events, and a date column that I can use to organize these events in chronological order.

I have it all basically set up but I am running into a design problem. I have a tablix with two columns in a group for the box+arrow combination, with column visibility set up to hide the arrow if it reaches the last event. What I would like to happen is for the boxes to reach the end of the page (the rightmost side of the page, and then come down a short distance below that row of boxes and continue on the same page (Ex. B). What it's doing is reaching the end of the side of the page, and breaking to the next page, effectively creating a bunch of pages with only one row of boxes on each page. (Ex. A)

Ex. A: What it does:
[image: What it does]

Ex. B: What I want it to do (accidentally forgot to include the arrow on the middle rightmost box in the picture, the second and third rows are just continuations of the first obviously):
[image: What I want it to do]

I would almost call it row wrapping but it's not exactly the same. To bring the problem away from my specific flow chart design, I want to make tablix columns wrap down directly below the table (not the content inside the columns, the actual columns themselves).

I've done some reading on column groupings and interactive page size. I don't really understand the column grouping manipulation, especially when trying to apply it to my situation, and the interactive page size doesn't seem to be what I am looking for either. Any help on this would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a multi-column layout, e.g.

http://nederveld.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/how-to-do-a-column-layout-in-sql-reporting-services/

Each of your Box + Arrow pairs would go into each cell.

I'm a bit confused about your arrow requirement, you might need to use an expression based on RowNumber to hide the arrow in the last column.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and it works like a charm, thanks! I wish they made things like this easier. The arrow is just a couple lines in a rectangle in an adjacent cell inside the column group with no border, if that makes sense. I have a query that is pulling these events that have an ID such that the later the event chronologically, the greater the ID, so I was hiding visibility of the arrow column if the event it was matched with was the final event. That's all I was saying about that, although I know your recommendation would definitely accomplish the same thing. Thanks again!